# Can't print contents of hash

Tags: arrays, perl, hash

Here's how I've set up my hash:

```
    my @keys_i_need = qw(A B C D E F G);

my %keys_i_need = map {$_ => []} @keys_i_need;

foreach my $line (@{$file_arr_ref}) {
    my $sub = substr( $line, 0, 1);
    if(($sub ne "#") and ($sub ne "")){
        my @key_vals = split(/\s+/, $line);
        my $key = shift @key_vals;
        if(exists $keys_i_need{$key}) {
            INFO("key is $key value is " . join(", ", @key_vals));
            push (@{$keys_i_need{$key}}, \@key_vals);
            DEBUG(Dumper \%keys_i_need);
        }
    }
}
```

If I understand this correctly, it's a hash, where each value is an array reference with array references inside the array reference. I don't want to use Dumper because I want to pick out each piece.

I'm trying to read out what's been pulled into the hash but I'm getting an error message that says:

`"my" variable $values masks earlier declaration in same statement at /home/rabdelaz/workspace/akatest_5/scripts/Viper/Stragglers.pl line 67.`

```
foreach my $key (keys %$config_options) {
    foreach my $arr_ref_of_arr_values (%$config_options{$key}) {
         foreach my $values (@$arr_ref_of_arr_values) { #<----------line 67
             foreach my $value (@$values) {
                 INFO("key $key has values $value");
             }
         }
    }
}
```

This looks right to me. I can't quite figure out what perl is complaining about. Any thoughts?

Comment: It's complaining about something you haven't shown us. There's going to be a `my $values` somewhere higher up in the code, and this is just a warning that you're overwriting it. The fact that your code doesn't work has nothing to do with it.

Comment: I thought the same thing at first. However, I don't see any other instances of "$values" in my code. Those are literally the only two instances of "$values" according to vim.

Comment: I just tried changing "$values" to "$vals" and still get the same complaint.

Comment: When you have to use four levels of nested loops, you might consider using a different data structure (or an object).

Comment: try this: `foreach my $arr_ref_of_arr_values ( %{$config_options{$key}}) { ...` notice how `$config_options{$key}` is entirely wrapped within `%{ ... }`.

Comment: when changing  "$values" to "$vals", does it complain about  "$values" or vals"?

Comment: @Hunter, if I understand this correctly, that would mean that the value at $config_options{$key} would itself be a hash? In fact it is a reference to an array.

Comment: @Hunter, in any case, I get this message when trying that: `Global symbol "%config_options" requires explicit package name at /home/rabdelaz/workspace/akatest_5/scripts/Viper/Stragglers.pl line 66.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see what I did now.
I was confused (once again) by the fact that an array reference is a scalar and not an array. Although, as you can see from my original code I went the wrong direction any way  (outside to the hash, rather than inside to the array ref. So my final code should look more like this:

```
foreach my $key (keys %$config_options) {
foreach my $arr_ref_of_arr_values ($$config_options{$key}) {
     foreach my $values (@$arr_ref_of_arr_values) { #<----------line 67
         foreach my $value (@$values) {
             INFO("key $key has values $value");
             }
         }
    }
}
```

In the course of debugging, I ended up with this to get the first value of the first array in the first key:

```
INFO("first value of first array of first key: " . ${${$$config_options{'A'}}[0]}[0]);
```

I then used this as my guidepost.